# Dynamically making indy use TLSv1.2

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

GitHub has stopped supporting TLS v1.0 and v1.1 (https://githubengineering.com/crypto-deprecation-notice/), so my code no longer wants to download from it. I have checked and it seems I need to make Indy use TLS v1.2, as stated here: [Using Indy 10 IdHTTP with TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809971/).

I have already updated the OpenSSL DLLs to the latest from http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/, and Indy seems to load them fine, but I still get an error.

The error I get:

[image: screenshot]

How can I make Indy use TLS v1.2 if I dynamically create Indy objects in a worker thread?

Current Code:

```
constructor TDownload.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; aurl, afilename: string);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  httpclient := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  httpclient.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36';
  httpclient.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(httpclient);
  httpclient.HandleRedirects := True;
  httpclient.OnWorkBegin := idhttp1WorkBegin;
  httpclient.OnWork := idhttp1Work;
  url := aurl;
  filename := afilename;
end;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to enable the `sslvTLSv1_2` flag in the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property ([only `sslvTLSv1` (TLS v1.0) is enabled by default](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181)), eg:

```
TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(httpclient.IOHandler).SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
```

Also note that you *might* have to also update the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.CipherList` property to enable TLS v1.2 ciphers.  Refer to the [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html) for the actual syntax.  By default, Indy uses `'AES:ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:+RC4:@STRENGTH'` if you don't specify your own `CipherList` value.

**Edit**: Indy no longer specifies a default cipher list. If the `SSLOptions.CipherList` property is empty, OpenSSL is now allowed to use whatever default cipher list it wants instead.

Comment: As an addendum, we should probably provide the Users with an updated default  CipherList and SSLVersion being set, if not done yet. It is likely that we would see those kind of errors more often in near future..

Comment: @FrederikA.Winkelsdorf actually, Indy has already been updated to no longer specify an outdated default `CipherList` so that OpenSSL can use its own default list instead. As for an updated default `SSLVersions`, that is [on the todo list](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181).